# Missing birthdays from fql

Tags: ruby, facebook-fql

I am retrieving birthdays from FQL and am getting some results back. My problem is that it seems as though some birthdays aren't coming through the API, but are visible to me if I browse a user's profile. Here is the FQL statement I am using:

> SELECT uid, name, birthday_date, profile_url, interests FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT >uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) AND substr(birthday_date, 0, 5) = \"09/17\"

Is there any reason why some birthdays wouldn't show up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Users can opt out of applications being able to allow friends apps to access their info under Privacy Settings -> Apps and Websites.

[image]

Comment: This. The reason why sometimes you need to ask for certain permissions on OpenGraph queries. And sometimes you don't. Trips us up all the time.